# importing a project from Perforce Eclipse Plugin as Java Project

Tags: eclipse, perforce, setup-project

I am trying import a project from Perforce workspace in Eclipse. It is importing it (fetching the files into java package hierarchy) but the problem is it is not importing as "Java project". so i can't edit the "Build path" or there is no classpath or something.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to put Eclipse metadata files into your source control system. All files starting with . in the project root along with entire .settings directory need to get checked in along with your source. If you don't do that, Eclipse will loose all knowledge of the type of projects that it is and how it supposed to be configured.

Comment: what files? .project? .metadata? the .project file is in the project directory. I am not sure where the .metadata file is

Comment: Not ".metadata". That's workspace metadata and you definitely do not want it in perforce. You want all "[project]/.*" files such as .project and .classpath. You also want project/.settings directory and all of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If your  Project in Perforce  do  not contain  files  of  regular Eclipse  java  projects  you can  create  another  project  with  Java  Nature.  Keep  Project  empty.

```
File > New > Java Project
```

It  will create  for  you following files.

```
.classpath
.project
.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

With this empty project  by  default  your  source folder  is  set  to "src".
Now  you have  to  copy  first  two  files  mentioned  above to  your Perforce workspace directory. Close and reopen project.

If  you  still have  issues  please  check  file .project. It  should  contain Nature  section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Dev-Project_03_04_2016</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Now  Check  your  .classpath File.  Since  you  copied  it  from  blank  project it  contains  something  like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>             
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>     
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You need to  remove  this  default  default "src"  folder  and  add  your  source folders, of  course  if  you wont  do  development  in eclipse  you  do  not need  all this. If  you did  everything correctly, andded  also JUnit Nature you  wil get something as  follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath> 
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="bb/apps/911access-zip/components/911emergencydriver-ejb/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="bb/apps/911access-zip/components/911accessmodel-ejb/src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="bb/apps/911access-zip/components/911accessplugin-ejb/src/main/java"/>  
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="bb/apps/911access-zip/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```